# How do you simplify variables which are powers?

Tags: logarithms

I have just started learning logarithms and I am struggling to solve the following

$$
\begin{equation}
2^a3^b = 6 \\ 
3^a4^b = 6
\end{equation}
$$

How can we solve for a and b in this case?

EDIT 1: Cleared up the two equations to increase understanding. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you trying to write two separate equations with different $a,b$?  Of course one of these equations like $2^a3^b=6$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: If you were to take the logarithm of everything, you'll have $\log(2^a3^b) = \log(3^a4^b)=\log(6)$.  Now, looking at the first more closely, remember that multiplication inside of a logarithm becomes addition outside, and exponents inside become factors outside, so the first expression can simplify as $\log(2^a3^b)=a\log(2)+b\log(3)$.  Similarly the other can simplify leaving you with $a\log(2)+b\log(3)=a\log(3)+b\log(4)=\log(6)$.  Can you continue from here?  Don't be afraid of $\log(2),\log(3),\dots$ they are just numbers like any other.

Comment: yep they're two different equations thanks for clarifying!

Comment: If it helps to simplify things in the end, it might be worth noting that $\log(4)=2\log(2)$ and that $\log(6)=\log(2)+\log(3)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I see! That makes a lot of sense! thank you so much for that tip! :D

Comment: @JMoravitz Apparently, you were faster :)

Comment: The solution is actually unique since the linear equation system we get has a unique solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Taking the natural logarithm on both sides , you get the linear equation system $$\ln(2)\cdot a+\ln(3)\cdot b=\ln(6)$$ $$\ln(3)\cdot a+\ln(4)\cdot b=\ln(6)$$ which should be easy to be solved.